# Start slideshow multiple images when click on one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I've got a html/php website and I want to load multiple images in a slideshow when I click on one. How can I do this? This is my code now:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 no_padding">
                    <div class="single_image">
                        <img src="images/w1.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="image_overlay">
                            <a href="">View Full Project</a>
                            <h2>Herent</h2>
                            <h4>Renovatie badkamer</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 no_padding">
                    <div class="single_image">
                        <img src="images/w2.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="image_overlay">
                            <a href="">View Full Project</a>
                            <h2>Mechelen</h2>
                            <h4>Plaatsen van keuken</h4>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 no_padding">
                    <div class="single_image">
                        <img src="images/w3.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="image_overlay">
                            <a href="">View Full Project</a>
                            <h2>Antwerpen</h2>
                            <h4>Verbouwingen</h4>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I searched for some templates and answers but I can't start with it.. It looks not that difficult...

Comment: Have you tried using a plugin like highslide or anything else?

Comment: not yet, thx for the tip!